# No SOAP/XML-RPC Sampler exists in JMeter 3.2

Tags: soap, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I was a bit surprised that my JMeter 3.1 scripts didn't work in 3.2.

What is the reason of removing SOAP/XML-RPC Sampler in JMeter 3.2? Is there some performance issue etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of the JMeter's [change](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) due to remove support of HTTPClient 3.1.

> SOAP/XML-RPC Request has been removed as part of Bug 60727. Use HTTP
>   Request element as a replacement.

See [Building SOAP request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create/update SOAP XML RPC Requests with new jmeter versions then do following things.

- List item

open Templates(right side top under 'File')--> Select Template Dropdown--> Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan ->Click on Create --> The Sample SOAP test plan with get created.

[image]
[image]

- List item

Under Number of Users -->HTTP Request(SOAP Request) sample will get created.

**Note:** sample http link of weather api is now changed, So you cant see any response.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP API option has been deprecated from JMeter updated version.

SO if you have any previous script for the API, then it will not work in updated versions of Jmeter.