# How to convert Jmeter 2.10 test to Jmeter 5

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way to convert Jmeter 2.10 tests to Jmeter 5, so I don't have to rewrite them all ?
Just trying to open them does not work, and cut paste from old to new does not work neither.
TY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you should be able to open the script created using JMeter 2.10 with the latest JMeter ([JMeter 5.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-released-td5728235.html) as of now).

If you cannot open the file - most probably there is a [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) missing which has to be reinstalled or there is another Test Element affected by [incompatible changes](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) which doesn't exist anymore like [SOAP Sampler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485848/no-soap-xml-rpc-sampler-in-jmeter-3-2) and has to be replaced.

You can figure out what element is causing the problem by looking into [JMeter log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) file

---

As the last resort you can record your test execution from JMeter 2.10 with JMeter 5.1

1. Prepare JMeter 5.1 for recording. The easiest way is going for [JMeter Templates](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#basic-instructions) feature, once you generate a Recording Template - start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Prepare JMeter 2.10 for recording. Add [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) configuration element (if it's not there) and set "Proxy Server Name" to `localhost` and "Port Number" to `8888`

   [image]
3. Run your test in JMeter 2.10 with 1 user and 1 iteration
4. JMeter 5.1 will capture the requests under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller).

Comment: ok, I saw we had a couple soap sampler.
I modified them for Http sampler and now it works. TY